# Storing non-literal js object in an html attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a big js library and I need to store an instance of a non-literal js object in an html attribute. Since I cannot write the whole js file here, this is a similar code:

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<script>
  function abc(){this.foo = Math.random(); ... } //The js object
  document.getElementById("abc").setAttribute("data-abc",new abc()); //Store the instance
  console.log(document.getElementById("abc").getAttribute("data-abc").foo); //Somehow I get undefined
</script>
```

I succeed to do it by using the JQuery.data function but I cannot use jquery here..How can I store the instance? Thanks.

Comment: Learn the basics: HTML data attributes can store strings, and the `String.prototype` does not have a `foo` attribute, hence you get undefined

Comment: Something worth noting is jQuery's data function doesn't actually store things in DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes only store String's so you could achieve this by using `JSON.stringify`, and `JSON.parse`

```
function abc(){this.foo = Math.random();}
document.getElementById("abc").setAttribute("data-abc",JSON.stringify(new abc()));
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("abc").getAttribute("data-abc")).foo);
```

however you could also just do this (unless you actually need to be able to convert everything back to HTML)

```
document.getElementById("abc").abc = new abc();
console.log(document.getElementById("abc").abc.foo);
```